btrfs: Cannot repair "bad extent [range] type mismatch with chunk"
I currently cannot mount my btrfs parition, even using the tools in systemrescue https://www.system-rescue.org/System-tools/ (btrfs-core v6.6.3.)
The mount command fails with a generic error and dmesg reports:
BTRFS info (device dm-0): block group 828547006464 len 35185445830656 mismatch with chuck 828547006464 len 10737341824
BTRFS info (device dm-0): failed to read block groups -117
BTRFS info (device dm-0):  open_ctree failed

btrfs check reports
[1/7] checking root items
[2/7] checking extends
Block group[8285470064664, 35185445830656] existed .
<repeat the following error with incremental ranges>
bad extent [881420435456, 881420451840), type mismatch with chunk
ERROR: errors found extent allocation tree or chunk allocation
[3/7]
cache and super generation don't match, space cache will be invalidated
[4/7] checking fs roots
[5/7] checking only csums items (without verfiying data)
[6/7] checking root refs
[7/7] checking quota groups skipped (not enabled on this FS)
found 481199640668 bytes used, error(s) found
total csum bytes: 45201008
total tree bytes: 10836148224
total fs tree bytes: 9729441792
total extent tree bytes: 493060096
btree space waste bytes: 2025793318
file data blocks allocated: 898991620096
 referenced 567020572672

The error bad extent [881420435456, 881420451840), type mismatch with chunk leads me to this old and hopefully irrelevant bug report about false positives: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1323464
It seems btrfs check --repair just loops printing the same error over and over, without actually fixing it, as reported here: How to fix btrfs extent issue
I don't have an ideal backup of my system, so I first like to take some data loss before restoring from backup. (I do, now, have a backup of this partition in this broken state.)
I've stumbled on btrfs check --init-extent-tree - is this the next step? Unfortunately, the docs include the warning:

Do not use unless you know what you’re doing.

I don't really know what I'm doing. Any informed suggestions?

From your choice of words, I stumbled upon the command btrfs restore - which still only presents me with new problems, after trying it out. Should I include snapshots? Why does my target partition with more space actually run out of space? Why does the restore fail due to permissions? Not that restore can't solve the problem, but the OP reported problems ALSO appear solvable.
